# Rails find individual model objects on the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently learning how to integrate stripe into a simple rails app, and am not sure what's the best way to allow users to choose among different products. Right now my set up is that I have all of my products listed out on the index page, and users can choose which product they wish to buy

**index.html.haml**

```
<% @products.each do |product|%>
    <%= product.description%>
    <%= product.price%>

    # Stripe payment button
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="A month's subscription"
          data-amount= <%= product.price*100%>
          data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

However, the `data-amount` listed is not the actual amount a customer will pay, because that is determined within the controller

**Products Controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @products = Product.all
    end

    def create
      # Amount in cents
      @amount = 500

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => 'example@stripe.com',
        :card  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
      )

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to charges_path
    end
end
```

As you can see, every product will be charged at $5 USD because of `@amount=500`. How do I dynamically change the `@amount` in the controller to each individual products price? I was thinking of maybe using each product's ID, but I can't simply call `@product = Product.find(params[:id])` since I have no params as this is the index page.

The code above is taken from [Stripe's rails checkout guide](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller,

You can grab the product first by doing something like this:

```
@product = Product.find_by(id: params[:product_id])
```

Then, just use:

```
@product.amount
```

instead of using the fixed `@amount`

Comment: Unfortunately, `Product.find_by(id:params[:product_id])` cannot pinpoint a single individual product, so `@product.amount` doesn't work either

Comment: I think., you should not do it in your index page. You can have a custom action and you should submit the product id to that action so that the controller can find the product accordingly. Also, if there is a column `amount` in the product table, then it will work and will give you the amount for the product.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails
This article also did not do it in the index page. They create a separate `charges_controller` and corresponding views to make it work. You can either do it their way, or create your custom action. But, `index` page is not the right place to do this.